# Android: Contextmenu on listview always selects last item in list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, contextmenu

I have created a listview with multiple values fetched from Mysql database in each item:

```
list = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CUST_TABLE);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable   
                        table = c.getString(TAG_TABLE);
                        String area = c.getString(TAG_AREA);
                        String user_name = c.getString(TAG_USER_NAME);
                        String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_TABLE, table);
                        map.put(TAG_AREA, area);
                        map.put(TAG_USER_NAME, user_name);
                        map.put(TAG_CITY, city);
                        QueueList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //return "success";
            return null;
        }

       protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CustTable.this, List,
                            R.layout.cust_queue_list_view, new String[] { TAG_TABLE, TAG_AREA, TAG_USER_NAME, TAG_CITY},
                            new int[] {  R.id.table, R.id.area, R.id.uname, R.id.city});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
```

Using ContextMenu, I am performing an operation on value "table" of the selected item of the listview.

```
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
         AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 1:
                    UserFunctions userFunction_new = new UserFunctions();
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    JSONObject json_new = userFunction_new.deleteUser(user_id, table);
                    return(true);    
         }
     return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
   }
```

However, the deleteUser function always work on the "table" value of the last item in the listview.

Any advise on how to make this work on the "table" value of the selected item will be helpful.

Also, I want to refresh the listview after each deleteUser function. I tried using `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();`

but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the below code in ContextMenu part (just above switch() line:                                               `HashMap<String,String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);                                                String table= value.get(TAG_TABLE);`